# Anything obviously suboptimal about this design?

Tags: rf, pcb-design

RF novice here, this is the first PCB I've designed and I'm just wondering if anyone more experienced than I (which is most people) sees anything glaringly wrong/bad/in need of improvement with this before I send off the Gerber files.

I'm working on a compact 1x4 distribution amplifier [schematic here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xrpfr.jpg) for wireless microphone use; frequency range of interest is 470-613 MHz. BNC input for antenna on left side, goes to high and low pass filters, then LNA, then an attenuator so that the device operates at unity gain input-to-output (factoring in the power divider and insertion loss of all the other components), then the power divider, to SMA outputs.

LNA receives power through a DC input jack (roughly outlined on right side of unit, with wires soldered to through holes in bottom right corner), diode for reverse polarity protection, and LDO regulator flanked by decoupling capacitors.

This is a 4 layer 63mil board. Top layer in red is RF signal (plus a couple traces for DC input); I did the math to ensure 50 ohm Zo throughout (14.6mil wide traces, 1.4mil thick copper, 6.7mil thick FR408 prepreg with Dk 3.69 @1GHz). 2nd layer in yellow is continuous ground plane. 3rd layer in pink is moving some DC supply voltage around, and bottom layer just has additional pads mirroring pads 1 and 3 of the SMA connectors to tie both sides of them to ground vias.

Would love to hear any feedback that folks have if there are any obvious issues with this layout; I'm an audio engineer not an RF engineer so this is all new for me! Assume I've done my homework and all the components have sufficient power handling for this application and I've followed the recommended application circuits where provided.

One specific question I have is that some of these components have recommended PCB layouts on their datasheets that presume the use of coplanar waveguide transmission lines. This design implements microstrip transmission lines throughout; what might some consequences be of failing to surround these components with a copper pour tied to the ground plane by vias?

Grateful to hear any thoughts you may have! Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Without the coplanar waveguides, you have the possibility of the signals coupling into others. I'd also suggest adding a ferrite bead on the dc input to stop radiation out that point and surround the board with vias to stop radiation out the sides of the pcb. As well, a ferrite bead on the output of the regulator to stop RF from upsetting it, reposition C2 to line up with the reg pins. Check your ceramic cap specs to ensure you're getting the required capacitance at the operating voltage - HiK caps have various deratings esp with voltage.

Comment: Those traces look pretty thin. You are sure you have 50 Ohms? The Z-height between the traces and the power planes must be pretty small. I agree with Kartman but I am also not an RF guru so...

Comment: The SMA outputs are rather tightly packed. SMA connectors should be tightened with a torque wrench for reliable connection. Is there enough room?

Comment: For FR4 material, W/H is about 2.0 for 50 ohms traces, so it looks like a very thin dielectric, which is possible if you have a foil/core/foil 4 layer construction. I prefer a core/prepreg/core 4 layer (RF across core, not prepreg). How are the connectors staked to the board? Narrow traces are easily breakable traces at the trace/pad interface to connectors which users may gorillarise. You need 3 x dielectric thickness clearance either side of your tracks for good impedance control, which it looks like you've got. A schematic of the circuit in your question would be useful.

Comment: @Neil_UK see schematic here- https://imgur.com/a/HwRfBFp

RF connectors are all SMD edge mount; SMAs have pads on both sides. Good to know about track clearance for impedance control; I was trying to avoid things running in parallel as much as possible but good to have a number for it! Thank you!

Comment: @Kartman, thanks for those suggestions! I'll definitely look into those.

Comment: @mkeith, it's a 4 layer 63mil board with .37mm traces, Dk of 3.69 @ 1GHz and 6.7mil FR408 substrate thickness- different calculators I've used have put it between 47 and 50 ohms.

Comment: @MarkLeavitt good consideration- dunno if I'll be able to get a proper socket over it but I'll at least be able to get a wrench of some sort across the flats. The footprints I found are a little generous as well, the outline indicated is definitely wider than the major diameter of the threads so they're not quite as close as they look.

Comment: Don't mix mils and mm, I want to be able to do W/H in my head. I've put your schematic link in your OP, all relevant info goes there, not in comments, so put dielectric thickness and trace width, in consistent mm, in there as well. Why not replace the attenuator with a pi-pad of three resistors? Smaller, cheaper, easier to control, easy enough to calculate values, bomb-proof below 1 GHz. With the extra space, move the regulator and RF apart, and maybe use a ferrite bead between regulator and RF. Some low frequency active devices misbehave when RF is nearby.

Comment: @Neil_UK copy that! (Man I wish we had gone metric!) Thanks for the suggestion on the pi-pad and ferrite bead, I'll look into it!

Comment: So it is 1600um overall thickness (more or less) but the dielectric between top layer and GND is only 170um. And the trace width is 370um. So the 50 Ohm impedance is plausible and no reason to doubt that the calculators have it wrong. Neil may have a different take which is fine. I don't do RF everyday, as I said previously.

Comment: So I've been looking into via fencing and other measures of controlling spurious EMR, and I'm wondering- would it be significantly advantageous to put all of my power components on the back side of the PCB and cover the whole top layer in a ground pour, tied with vias to the internal ground plane throughout, using CPW for the RF signal trace? Or would simply utilizing appropriately spaced ground vias on the board as-is provide decent protection against spurious EMR?